# Can I open any app from app store in xcode?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, xcode, swift

I just start learning iOS development and still haven't finish the course but I'm too curios to know if I can open an app from app store in xcode to see all of the code inside of it as it will make it easy to learn.

Comment: Disassembling object code (apps, libraries, binaries) is a valuable skill, but it's way up there on the difficulty level. Far better to learn from source code projects initially IMO, but to each their own path!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No for two reasons.

1. You can only load programs that you have built.
2. Many programs (includingf those written in Objective C and Swift) are compiled into machine code so that the code that the author wrote is not in the resulting app.